# Aligning popup window near the button clicked

Tags: android

I have a custom popup window by a layout. I have to give a x,y coordinates to appear popup window after `a_btn` click. This can be different locations in different phones.

But I want to show the popup window always above and touching the the `a_btn`

How can I implement this.Help me

My code for showing the popup window :

```
a_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater lInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popup_view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_a, null);
            final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popup_view,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
            popup.showAtLocation(relative, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, coordinateTop, 100);
            //popup.showAsDropDown(location_popup_view,  2, 2);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `popup.showAsDropDown(a_btn,0,0);`

instead of 
`popup.showAtLocation(relative, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, coordinateTop, 100);`

and gave xoff and yoff.

```
a_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {    
LayoutInflater lInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popup_view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_a, null);
        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popup_view,200,200,true);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
        popup.showAsDropDown(a_btn,0,0);


    }
});
```

Comment: I think you need to include also the dpi level of the device and then multiply it by the position you want

Answer (score 1):

Use this code will help you

```
a_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Rect r = locateView(v);    
    LayoutInflater lInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popup_view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_a, null);
            final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popup_view,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
            popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, r.right, r.bottom);


        }
    });



    public static Rect locateView(View v) {
            int[] loc_int = new int[2];
            if (v == null)
                return null;
            try {
                v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                return null;
            }
            Rect location = new Rect();
            location.left = loc_int[0];
            location.top = loc_int[1];
            location.right = loc_int[0] + v.getWidth();
            location.bottom = loc_int[1] + v.getHeight();
            return location;
        }
```